# Prgrama em C# com falha

Tags: c

Poderiam me ajudar a acha o que tem de errado neste programa?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ordena (float *num1, float *num2);

void main (void){
    
    float a,b;
    printf("Digite dois valores separados por espaco:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    
    ordena (&a, &b);
    printf("Os numeros em ordem crescente sao: %d\n", a, b);
    
}

void ordena (float *num1, float *num2) {
    
    if (*num1 > *num2) {
    
        float temp;
        temp=*num1;
        *num1=*num2;
        *num2=temp;
    
}
}
```

Comment: Consegui fazer retornar os dois valores, mas estão vindo como "0" .                    #include <stdio.h>

void ordena (float *num1, float *num2);

void main (void){
 
 float a,b;
 printf("Digite dois valores separados por espaco:\n");
 scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
 
 ordena (&a, &b);
 printf ("\n\nOs numeros em ordem crescente sao: %d  %d\n",a,b);
 
}

void ordena (float *num1, float *num2) {
 
 if (*num1 > *num2) {
 
  float temp;
  temp=*num1;
  *num1=*num2;
  *num2=temp;
 
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está em C, não em C#.

No scanf e no printf, o %d é usado caso sua entrada seja números inteiros, como são float, você deve usar %f.
Exemplo:

```
scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
```

Dessa forma deve funcionar, mas provavelmente os números vão vir com muitas casas decimais, então no printf você pode adicionar um .1f para os números aparecerem com apenas uma casa decimal.
Exemplo:

```
printf("Os numeros em ordem crescente sao: %.1f, %.1f", a, b);
```

Ou você pode usar int em vez de float.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Você está misturando os tipos de dados [int](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/c-language/type-int?view=msvc-170) e [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/c-language/type-float?view=msvc-170) na sua leitura.

Se é realmente necessário utilizar o tipo `float` então tens que trocar o tipo de leitura

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ordena (float *num1, float *num2);

void main (void){
    
    float a,b;
    printf("Digite dois valores separados por espaco:\n");
    scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
    
    ordena (&a, &b);
    printf("Os numeros em ordem crescente sao: %.2f %.2f \n", a, b);
    
}

void ordena (float *num1, float *num2) {
    
    if (*num1 > *num2) {
    
        float temp;
        temp=*num1;
        *num1=*num2;
        *num2=temp;
    
    }
}
```

No meu ver pode ser trocado para leitura de valores inteiros, trocando somente os caracteres de leitura

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ordena (int *num1, int *num2);

void main (void){
    
    int a,b;
    printf("Digite dois valores separados por espaco:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    
    ordena (&a, &b);
    printf("Os numeros em ordem crescente sao: %d %d\n", a, b);
    
}

void ordena (int *num1, int *num2) {
    
    if (*num1 > *num2) {
    
        int temp;
        temp=*num1;
        *num1=*num2;
        *num2=temp;
    
    }
}
```

Referência

[Controle de caracteres de leitura](https://documentation.help/CppReference/scanf1.html)

[C plus plus doc](https://cplusplus.com/doc/)

[Microsoft C++ learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/?view=msvc-170)